# Pivot a resultset (rows to columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following #table:

```
guid  field  value
--------------------
123   A      foo
123   B      foobar
123   C      123
234   A      bar;baz
234   B      3464
345   A      foobaz
```

I need to transpose / pivot this into the following #table2:

```
guid  A        B        C
---------------------------
123   foo      foobar   123
234   bar;baz  3464     -
345   foobaz   -        -
```

In other words: the `guid` needs to stay the table key but all the `field`s need to be transposed into columns.

Is this possible in SQL Server?

Usually, I would use a server-side (php, python, asp) script to pull `#table` from the database and transpose the resultset by iterating to the resultset as an array but this is not an option in this case. I need a sql-only solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of fields?

Comment: @franglais No, the number of fields varies anywhere between 0 and 800 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should pivot your data and will keep your GUID.

```
select tbl.guid, tbl.[A], tbl.[B], tbl.[C] from (
  select * from (
    select guid, field, value
    from #table
  ) t
  pivot (
    max(value) for field in ([A],[B],[C])
  ) p
) tbl
```

Creating your columns in preparation for the dynamic SQL:

```
declare @columns nvarchar(max) = (select stuff((
    select distinct ',[' + t.field + ']'
    from #table t
    for xml path('')
),1,1,''))
```

Mixing the columns into the dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql = N'
select tbl.guid, ' + @columns + ' from (
    select * from (
        select guid, field, value
        from #table
    ) t
    pivot (
        max(value) for field in (' + @columns + ')
    ) p
) tbl'
```

And execute:

```
execute (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks @atom.gregg. This would work perfectly I guess if there would be 3 fixed fields. That's a mistake in the OP btw - I forgot to mention that the number of `fields` varies. Is there a way of automating this (first reading the distinct fieldlist and then pivot?)

Comment: You would need to use dynamic SQL. First produce your comma-delimited column list into a variable. Then create your SQL with this within. Then execute your SQL.

Comment: Good answer, your pivot snippet helped me.